# How to resolve Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 13) TypeError: Network request failed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I am trying to build React_Native app with Expo and was trying to integrate Stripe in it. I have some Issues that occurs:

The following is my server.mjs file:

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys


import express from 'express'
import Stripe from 'stripe'

const app = express();
const port = 8080

// I don t put my key here(on stack) for security reason
const STRIPE_SK = "my_secret_key"
const stripe = Stripe(STRIPE_SK,{apiVersion: "2022-11-15"});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to http://localhost:${port}`);
});

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: 1099,
            currency: 'ron',
            automatic_payment_methods: {
                enabled: true,
              },
        });

        const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret;
        
        res.json({
            clientSecret: clientSecret
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        res.json({error: e.message})
    }
})
```

The following is my Card.js file:

```
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { CardField, initStripe, StripeProvider, useConfirmPayment } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native'
import Dialog from "react-native-dialog"
import { auth, database } from "../../../firebase"
import { onValue, ref, set } from '@firebase/database'

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080"

const STRIPE_PK = 'my_publish_key'

const Card = ({showCard, hideCard}) => {

    const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [cardDetails, setCardDetails] = useState()
    const {confirmPayment, loading } = useConfirmPayment()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid
        const userRef = ref(database, 'users/' + userId);
        onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val()
            setUserId(userId);
            setUsername(data.email)
        })
    }, [])

    const fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/create-payment-intent`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

        const { clientSecret, error } = await response.json();
        return { clientSecret, error };
    };

    const handlePayPress = async () => {
        if(!cardDetails?.complete || !userId || !username) {
            Alert.alert("Please enter card details")
            return
        }
        // Gather the customer's billing information (for example, email)
        const billingDetails = {
          userId: userId,
          username: username
        };
    
        // Fetch the intent client secret from the backend

        try{
            const { clientSecret, error } = await fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret();
            if(error) {
                console.log("Unable to process payment")
            } else {
                const {paymentIntent, error} = confirmPayment(
                    clientSecret, 
                    {
                        type: "Card",
                        billingDetails: billingDetails,
                    }
                );
                if(error) {
                    console.log(`Payment confimation error ${error.message}`);
                } else if (paymentIntent){  
                    alert("Payment Succesful");
                    console.log("Payment succesful ", paymentIntent);
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };
    

    return (
        <StripeProvider
            publishableKey={STRIPE_PK}

        >
            <Dialog.Container visible={showCard}>
                <CardField
                    postalCodeEnabled={false}
                    cardStyle={styles.card}
                    style={styles.cardContainer}
                    onCardChange={cardDetails => {
                        setCardDetails(cardDetails);
                    }}
                >
                </CardField>
                <Dialog.Button 
                    disabled={loading} 
                    style={{color: "green"}}   
                    label="Confirma" 
                    onPress={handlePayPress}
                />
                <Dialog.Button 
                    style={{color: "red"}} 
                    label="Anuleaza" 
                    onPress={hideCard}
                />
            </Dialog.Container>
        </StripeProvider>
    )
}

export default Card

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardContainer: {
        // flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        height: 50, 
        width: '90%',
        color: 'grey'
    },
    card: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey'
    },
})
```

With this code I am trying to add and get informations to and from Stripe payments. At start I use two things:

1. Start local host with **nodemon server.mjs** and gets:
   [image]

2. Start expo project with **npx expo start**.

***The Issue after entering the card details correct and hitting button that activates **handlePayPress** function is the following:***

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 13):
TypeError: Network request failed
http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:21526:33
http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26585:26
_callTimer@http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26524:17
callTimers@http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26680:19
__callFunction@http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:20182:36
http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19944:31
__guard@http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:20134:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://192.168.100.5:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19943:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Comment: Since the error seems to indicate that the network request failed, I suspect it is your fetch request that is not completing successfully, but have you added any logging to your code to confirm which line causes the error you're encountering? If it is the fetch, have you checked your server-side logs to see if the request is making it there successfully, and if so whether the server-side code encountered any errors while processing the request?

Comment: try providing actual local ip address in place of localhost from app